# How to append free text elements from array to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to append information to my page from two different JavaScript arrays. It looks like this.

```
var i = 0;
var videoArr=["big long array"];
var descriptArr=["big long array"];

function appendVideo(i) {
    var url = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoArr[i] + "/mqdefault.jpg";
    $("#history").append("<img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"120\" height=\"68\" />**NEED TO PRINT descriptArr[i] HERE**<br />");
}

function loadHistory() {
    while (i < '.$length.') {
        appendVideo(i);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

So the above code is appending all the elements from the videoArr no problem. The problem is the descriptArr is full of free text descriptions that I need to print beside each videoArr element. What's he best way to do this? I presume it's not document.write(descriptArr[i])...

Comment: Have you tried concatenating `descriptArr[i]`?

Comment: Why can't you just do it the same way you did `url` and `videoArr[i]`?

Comment: @Kevin $("#history").append("<img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"120\" height=\"68\" />descriptArr[i]<br />") just writes the word 'descript[i]' beside all the videoArr elements

Comment: @AzzyDude when you dou `videoArr[i]` you get a string. when you do `descript[i]` you get a string. You can concatenate strings with `+`. Don't forget that if it is in quotes, it won't get executed by javascript and will instead be treated as a string. `$("#history").append("<img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"120\" height=\"68\" />" + descriptArr[i] + "<br />") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as long as you are sure that descriptArr does not contain any HTML literals.

```
$("#history").append("<img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"120\" height=\"68\" />" + descriptArr[i] + "<br />");
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. You just barely got it before kugaevsky, lol

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way, but just try something like this

```
$("#history").append("<img src=\"" + url + "\" width=\"120\" height=\"68\" />" + descriptArr[i] + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive used this for achieving the same thing:

```
aDate = (document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
$('.daysContain').find('div').eq(dateArray.length-1).prepend(aDate + '<br>');
```